# Partition error being reported by only some programs

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I am getting an error about the partitions on one of my drives.

I checked my hard disk with Acronis Disk Director 11 Home, HDTunePro, MiniTool Partition Wizard, Hddscan, HDD Regenerator 2011, WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics, GParted, and Parted Magic, but none of them found any problems with the drive. However, when I perform a check with PartitionGuru, DiskGenius, and an old version of Partition Magic (8.0), I get the following error (seen below) about the partition being bad and needing to reformat to fix it:

> Error - The number of sectors record in DBR overflow - Reformat

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Should I reformat or not? I checked two other hard drives, one of them like my 500 WD Blue, and neither has any errors with *any* programs.

Are there any other programs that can check partitions for errors?

Finally, how should a large SATA hard disk be formatted? I currently use programs like GParted, Acronis Disk Director, or MiniTool Partition Wizard. Are these programs good for formatting a new hard disk? Could the choice of format tool be the cause of the error?

This is the report from GParted (all checks are OK except this):

```
check file system on /dev/sda5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:04    ( SUCCESS )

ntfsresize -P -i -f -v /dev/sda5

ntfsresize v2012.1.15AR.5 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda5
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 416090681856 bytes (416091 MB)
Current device size: 416090684928 bytes (416091 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Accounting clusters ...
Found backup boot sector in the middle of the volume.
Space in use : 151623 MB (36.4%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Estimating smallest shrunken size supported ...
File feature Last used at By inode
$MFT : 214728 MB 0
Multi-Record : 212846 MB 37659
$MFTMirr : 1 MB 1
Ordinary : 214808 MB 6
You might resize at 151622209536 bytes or 151623 MB (freeing 264468 MB).
Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
```

Comment: Just post what the message is. You are more likely to get help than by linking to it.

Comment: Contact the author of the software and ask what it means, some errors are written by the author and do not reflect what is really wrong if anything, Google returns nothing for that error text.

Comment: I have had problems partitioning because of faulty connections. Is the HD externally powered? Do you have another connector to try it with.

Comment: How did you create the partition(s) on that drive?

Comment: thanks every body for help and this hard is main hard disk and i format with Acronis Disk Director 11 Home or MiniTool Partition Wizard

i don't remember but it's working good and all of my connectors are true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things is likely happening here:

- The program you used to create the partitions made some non-standard edits to the partition table (which may or—more likely—may not be a problem)
- The programs returning the error are older/simpler and returning false positives

The fact is that disk structures have a bunch of obsolete data that is not used in modern systems (e.g., 16-bit fields). Some programs modify these when creating, modifying, or formatting partitions, others ignore them since they are likely to be meaningless these days. Likewise, some programs check these for consistency (even if they *cannot* be correct), others ignore them.

The fact that you specifically mentioned and *old* version of Partition Magic as one of the complaining programs indicates that what has probably happened is that one of the obsolete fields has an “incorrect” value, and the older/simpler programs are throwing an error while the newer ones know to ignore it.

<sup>(When I run Partition Magic for DOS on my drives that were partitioned with a newer version of Easeus for Windows, Partition Magic complains about some errors even though the drives work just fine in both Windows and DOS. If I let PM for DOS fix the errors, my FAT32 partitions continue to work fine, but my NTFS partitions disappear so I have to manually restore the partition table values (thankfully I made copy of the data before letting it “fix” them).)</sup>

The error you are seeing is complaining about the number of sectors recorded in the master boot record. As you [can see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record#Sector_layout), the format of the MBR has changed over time as drives grew larger and larger. The programs in question are probably using a different format of the master boot record  (`DBR` probably means ***`DOS`***`Boot Record`).

So what should you do? Unless you are going to access the drive in DOS (which would require an NTFS driver TSR anyway), then you don’t really have to do anything. If the drive is working fine and checking the volume with `chkdsk` doesn't give any errors, then you don’t have to worry; the errors are just false positives by old/simple programs that are not up-to-date. (You can check for newer versions of those programs to see if they have been updated to recognize modern drive structures.)

Comment: thanks sir for help i will do you advise and not do anything if no errors or problems appear to me and about program partitons program yes DiskGenius and Partition Magic (8.0) are old of course but PartitionGuru i have latest version from it and here is site 
http://www.eassos.com/partitionguru/free-download.php

and this program appear to me that i have error and this program aren't old as you see so i'm not make sure if this really error or just fake because this program not support new hard disk

but i will wait for any errors thank you man for help

Comment: No problem. Did you try running `chkdsk` to find actual errors in the volume itself?

Comment: of course i used chkdsk and tell me no errors found but when i checked again with gparted magic he appear to me that no errors found but show me this message in report
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SSfRXtqLzTlOff4krJ7sgzijmFvXGZfOpTLIdOLW51Y/edit)